# error_message partial not rendered in Rails 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have problems displaying `error_messages.html.erb` partial when building custom validation.

I have for instance, a form to make a transaction, which starts like:

```
<%= form_for @transaction do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
```

I have a validation which prevents a user from making a transaction with himself:

```
validate :self_transaction_not_possible
```

with

```
    def self_transaction_not_possible
      bel = Belonging.find_by_id(self.belonging.id)
      unless bel.nil?
        if self.user_id == bel.user_id
          errors.add(:base, "You cannot perform a transaction with yourself")
        end
      end
    end
```

Then I ran such an example in the browser (initiate a transaction on a belonging I own), and I placed a debugger inside self_transaction_not_possible. I checked that the validation happens, and indeed, inside the debugger, I see that typing: self.errors.full_messages give me my error message, so validation seems to be performed...

I would then have expected, as the object was not valid, that the error message would appear in my view, but no ... putting the debugger inside the `error_messages.html.erb` partial showed me that object.errors.any remains == {}  :-/ ...

The user is then redirected towards the page it should see when the saving process fails (validation has been performed correctly), but he never sees the error message ...

Am I missing something obvious ?  ...

Comment: It's hard to distinguish your typing errors from real bugs: `<%= form_for @transaction, do |f| %>` - what the comma is doing here? `<%= render 'shared/error_messages'; :object => f.object %>` - why did you put semicolon here? `unless bel.nil ?` - space after `nil` was intentional? And so on...

Comment: @jdoe: ok, I typed too fast and I couldn't do a copy/paste due to a network issue. Anyway, question is now typo-free (I hope)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK ... the reason it failed was because I was doing a REDIRECT_TO in the controller when the transaction was not being saved, thereby deleting the `@transaction.errors` vector ...

Changing this to a `render :template => 'transactions/edit'` solved my issue ..

Of course, it was hard to guess looking at the question :-/ ...